# BreezeJS + Knockout Not able to set input field to Null

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

Where a model uses nullable values such as

```
public Nullable<int> Price { get; set; }
```

When adding new records all is fine, Price is Not a required field so will be saved as Null value in the database.

If I modify an existing record, let’s say I want to change the value of price from 10 to blank. Then I get a validation error.

Validation error: ‘Price‘ must be an integer between the values of -2147483648 and 2147483647

However this field is not required so I would have expected it to just save a null value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because empty textbox value is **""** (empty string), but not **null**.

So, before setting new value you should check if value is empty string, if so - assign *null* manually.

---

Update for Knockout.
You can write custom ko binding, that will do everything for you.
Here is example (might be not the best one):

**Javascript:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.nullableValue = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var underlyingObservable = valueAccessor();
    var interceptor = ko.dependentObservable({
        read: underlyingObservable,
        write: function (value) {
            if (value == '') {
                underlyingObservable(null);
                return;
            }
            underlyingObservable(value);
        }
    });
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, function () { return interceptor; }, allBindingsAccessor);
  },
  update: ko.bindingHandlers.value.update
};
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="nullableValue: myNullableProperty" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question it make it more clear, I am using knockout and MVVM so I don't write any code to update the value, I believe the problem lies in the BreezeJS library.

Comment: While you certainly can write a custom binding, we don't think you should have to for this common case. We will improve our DataType.Parse logic to handle this properly; can't say how soon ... but soon.